# Running Google Script Function in HTML JavaScript Header section

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a function that is defined in my Google App Script (code.gs) called myFunction() which accesses information from a Google Sheet. I want to be able to call this function from the script header in the html file where a HTML form is generated. I have tried running google.script.run.myFunction() in the script header of the HTML page however it doesn't return any variable, just undefined. A code snippet for the header of the HTML is below.

```
<script>
function getArray(){
    var equipment = google.script.run.myFunction();
    console.log(equipment);
  } 
</script>
```

When looking at the console.log the output is undefined. I have tried changing the output of myFunction to many other types of outputs and when I use the Logger.log function in the GS, it outputs the correct variable however it simply doesn't transfer over to the HTML form. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I am doing it in this way as I am using this variable to dynamically created checkboxes in the HTML form and this is the simplest way I can think of doing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to receive a return value is with the:

```
.withSuccessHandler(myHandlerFunction)
```

The complete code would be:

```
<script>
function getArray(){
   google.script.run
     .withSuccessHandler(myHandlerFunction)
     .myFunction();
  }

  function myHandlerFunction(equipment) {
    console.log('equipment: ' + equipment);
  };
</script>
```

[Apps Script Documentation - run methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#methods)

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I didn't realise the SuccessHandler was required. Really appreciate it!